# GetQueuedCompletionStatus - как узнать "тип" готовой задачи?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот когда в очереди порта завершения появляется готовая задача, то извлекая ее с помощью функции `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, как узнать - эта готовая задача на чтение или запись ?

Или я вручную, как то сам должен это отслеживать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На каждую операцию должна быть своя `OVERLAPPED` структура. По указателю на `OVERLAPPED` структуру можно понять, что именно готово.

В `OVERLAPPED` нет места для данных программы, но сама она выделяется программой, так что за ними можно следить (Или за hEvent в ней).

Comment: Пользовательские данные можно передавать через Completion Key.